# How to unset a js file from a Drupal6 installation: Doesn´t work with "remove-scripts[]" in my template file

Tags: javascript, drupal, unset

I´ve added to my template.tpl.php file inside my drupal theme this line to elimiante the calling to a specific css file:

```
remove-stylesheets[all][] = modules/system/system.css
```

If I want to do that with a specific js file, could I just do this?:

```
remove-scripts[] = whatever.js
```

I´ve tried it, but it doesn´t seems to work...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in your template file.

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $js = drupal_add_js();
  unset($js['module']['sites/all/modules/yourmodule/yourjs.js']); 
  $vars['scripts'] = $js;
}
```

This function will be called before the template is processed and rendered to the browser. If you are not sure about the path to your js file, print the `drupal_add_js()` array and find the path to the required js.

Comment: Thanks! If it´s a theme js file, should I replace ['module'] with ['theme']?

Comment: just give a `print_r(drupal_add_js());` and check the output. You will have a clear idea on how it is structured.